# Find security weaknesses in this website (exam question)

Tags: php, xss, vulnerability, injection

I am currently studying for a computer security exam and I am stuck on the following question from a past exam paper

[image: Question]

```
1c  <form action=”message.php” method=”get”>
2c  <p>Message: <input type=”text” name=”message” /></p>
3c  <p>Username: <input type=”text” name=”user” /></p>
4c  <p>Password: <input type=”text” name=”pass” /></p>
5c  <p><input type=”submit” /></p>

1s  <?php
2s  $user = $ ̇REQUEST[”user”];
3s  $pass = $ ̇REQUEST[”pass”];
4s  $message = $ ̇REQUEST[”message”];
5s  $result = mysqli_multi_query($con,”UPDATE messages SET
6s     message=”.$message.” WHERE user=”.$user.””);
7s  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
8s  if (!empty($row)) {
9s     echo ”Your message: ”.$message.” has been added”;
10s   }
11s  ?>
```

I know I should look for things like SQL injection, XSS, Cross-site request forgery, etc ...

My attempt:

- $user could be used for SQL injection as it is not sanitized
- password is not verified anywhere (?)
- echo $message also looks like vulnerable part (input not sanitized again) but not sure what would be the exploit (some sort of XSS?)

I would really appreciate if someone could highlight the vulnerable parts of the code or even explain why they are vulnerable.

Comment: are there four?

Comment: @vipulnair At least six, from a quick look!

Comment: @ischelp 1.sql injection 2.csrf 3stored xss by changing other user messages 4.reflected xss using csrf.

Comment: @VipulNair could you please tell me the line numbers/ or parts of the code that are vulnerable to these attacks?

Comment: CSRF because csrf token check is missing.sql injection at 5s.Stored XSS at 5s because of logic error you can insert a message for other user.No authentication check.Reflected xss at 9s.Also using GET for sending password will show up in browser history.BUT AGAIN YOU SHOULD WAIT FOR @matthew's reply

Comment: Between you you've got 5 - I'd add password being entered in text input rather than password input (shoulder surfing risk), and using a multiple query function when only a single query is expected (not sufficient to prevent sqli on its own, but would make abusing this one harder, since it's an update).

Comment: What about sensitive information is transmitted in the URL (password because the form method is GET)

Comment: By the way, it's not about the answers. It's about understanding the code what an attacker can do to it. If this is not clear, I suggest to study a bit more rather than asking for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Vulnerabilities 1 & 2:**

```
5s  $result = mysqli_multi_query($con,”UPDATE messages SET
6s     message=”.$message.” WHERE user=”.$user.””);
```

These are SQL injection vulnerabilities. The program invokes a SQL query built using input coming from an untrusted source. As you pointed out `$USER` is vulnerable but `$message` is also.

**Vulnerability 3:**

```
8s  if (!empty($row)) {
9s     echo ”Your message: ”.$message.” has been added”;
10s   }
```

This is an XSS vulnerability. Although it is hard to classify specifically the type given the little amount of source code, because the data is being stored in a DB (thus making it persistent); however the example code does not show other areas it is output, so we can only state that it is reflected at this point.

**Potential Vulnerability 4:**

```
3s  $pass = $ ̇REQUEST[”pass”];
```

Computer programs depend largely on context, so while it appears that the author of this program wanted to authenticate, this may not be the case. If the author did want to authenticate, then `$pass` is not checked anywhere. Regardless of if this is a vulnerability, this is unused code. It is bad practice to leave unused code in a production program.

**Potential Vulnerability 5:**
`1c  <form action=”message.php” method=”get”>`

This is potentially a CSRF vulnerability. Once again this is dependent on the programmers intent to have validation. If they did then the form post must contain a user-specific secret in order to prevent an attacker from making unauthorized requests.

**Potential Vulnerabilities 6 & 7:**

```
5s  $result = mysqli_multi_query($con,”UPDATE messages SET
6s     message=”.$message.” WHERE user=”.$user.””);
```

`$message` and `$USER` are potentially stored XSS vulnerabilities, although the sample code does not show these variables getting retrieved, it would be fairly safe to assume these may be displayed in another part of the program.

**Potential Vulnerability 8:**
`4c  <p>Password: <input type=”text” name=”pass” /></p>`

This is potentially a shoulder surf vulnerability. This input should be obfuscated. Once again this depends on the programmers intent to actually validate, and the actual meaning of the `pass` input field. We can assume that this is a password, but unless we get confirmation from the programmer, it is just that, an assumption.

**Potential Vulnerability 9:**

```
1c  <form action=”message.php” method=”get”>
2c  <p>Message: <input type=”text” name=”message” /></p>
3c  <p>Username: <input type=”text” name=”user” /></p>
4c  <p>Password: <input type=”text” name=”pass” /></p>
5c  <p><input type=”submit” /></p>
```

This is potentially a shoulder surf vulnerability. This will result in a GET request displaying the password on the URL, which could result in a shoulder surf attack. Once again this is dependent on the programmer' intent.

Comment: Besides the fact that the password is shown in the URL, it will also be stored in proxy server and web server logs.